# Proving norm of coset is same as norm of some vector in that coset

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a nontrivial subspace of a finite dimensional vector space $U$ with a positive definite scalar product. I want to prove that for each $[u]\in U / V$ there is a $w\in[u]$ such that $\|[u]\|=\|w\|$.

I have the definition of a norm over a quotient space as $\|[u]\|=\inf\{\|x\|\mid x\in[u]\}$ for $[u]\in U/V$. Doesn't this definition have built into it that the there is a vector $w\in U$ such that $\|[u]\|=\|w\|$? In this case doesn't my definition directly imply what I am trying to prove?

Comment: what is a *positive definite* scalar product? Do you mean **inner** product?

Comment: Assuming that; what you know is that if $x \in U$ then $\|[u]\| \leq \|x\|$. Why do you feel that the definition implies this is an equality?

Comment: @guidoar My definition of a positive definite scalar product is a scalar product $(\cdot,\cdot)$ such that $(u,u)\geq 0$ for all $u\in U$ and $(u,u)=0$ if $u=0$.

Comment: @guidoar If this is a finite dimensional vector space, then the infimum turns into a minimum, and now this norm is the minimum of all vector norms in this coset which means it is the same as the norm of a vector in that coset?

Comment: @guidoar Sorry, I did not mean equality, it may have been confusing using the $x$ again in my question, but I just edited this.

Comment: Oh, okay. Usually a scalar product is the function $k \times V \to V$ defining the vector space structure, hence my question. As for the latter; *why* is the infimum a minimum?

Comment: @guidoar On second thought, I realized that there are infinitely many vectors in a coset, so this is where my logic is completely flawed. But now I have no idea how I could show this, or why it is true?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** in **any** normed space, finitely dimensional subspaces are closed. On the other hand, in finitely dimensional normed spaces a subset is comapct if and only if it is closed and bounded.

Fix $x \in V$ and consider $F = x+U$. Since the translation $T_x(y) = y+x$ is a homeomorphism, the set $F$ is closed. Note that

$$
\|[x]\| = \inf \{\|y\| : y \in x+U\} = d(0,F). 
$$

However, for some arbitrary $y_0 \in F$ we moreover have

$$
\|[x]\| = \inf\{\|y\| : y \in F\} = \inf\{\|y\| : y \in F, \|y\| \leq\|y_0\| \}.
$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thank you for this hint. It makes sense that is finite dimensional subspaces are closed then it quotient space contains all limit points, so the infimum is in the space. I see how this proves what I am trying to show, but I do not follow this method of translating the space when you introduce an arbitrary $y_0$ or where this is going?

Comment: I did not understand your first sentence. My point is that you want to prove that $d(0,F)$ is a minimum. There are various ways to do this. One is to note that $d(0,F) = d(0, F \cap B_{\|y_0\|}(0))$. Now the latter is an infimum over a compact set; and we're done. Please do ask if this is still unclear